# Cost of inlining methods in C#

Tags: c#, performance, inline, quicksort

I've recently implemented a QuickSort algorithm in C#. Sorting on an integer array containing millions of items, the code's performance is approximately 10% behind .NET's implementation.

```
private static void QS(int[] arr, int left, int right)
{
    if (left >= right) return;

    var pIndex = Partition(arr, left, right);
    QS( arr, left, pIndex);
    QS( arr, pIndex + 1, right);
}
```

On an array of 5 million items, this code is about 60ms slower than .NET's.

Subsequently, I created an another method that has the `Partition()` method inlined into `QS()` (eliminating the method call and the `return` statement). This however resulted in a drop in perfomance to about 250ms slower than .NET's sort method.

Why does this happen?

*Edit:* This is the code the `Partition()` method. In the inlined version of `QS()`, the entire content of this method with the exception of the `return` statement replaces the `var pIndex = Partition(arr, left, right);` line.

```
private static int Partition(int[] arr, int left, int right)
{
    int pivot = arr[left];
    int leftPoint = left - 1;
    int pIndex = right + 1;
    int temp = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        do { pIndex--; } while (arr[pIndex] > pivot);
        do { leftPoint++; } while (arr[leftPoint] < pivot);

        if (leftPoint < pIndex)
        {
            temp = arr[leftPoint];
            arr[leftPoint] = arr[pIndex];
            arr[pIndex] = temp;
        }
        else { break; }
    }
    return pIndex;
}
```

*Edit #2:*
In case anyone's interested in compiling, here's the code that calls the algorithms:

*Edit #3:*
New test code from Haymo's suggestion.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const int globalRuns = 10;
    const int localRuns = 1000;

    var source = Enumerable.Range(1, 200000).OrderBy(n => Guid.NewGuid()).ToArray();
    var a = new int[source.Length];

    int start, end, total;

    for (int z = 0; z < globalRuns; z++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Run #{0}", z+1);

        total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < localRuns; i++)
        {
            Array.Copy(source, a, source.Length);
            start = Environment.TickCount;
            Array.Sort(a);
            end = Environment.TickCount;
            total += end - start;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t\tTtl: {1}ms\tAvg: {2}ms", ".NET", total, total / localRuns);

        total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < localRuns; i++)
        {
            Array.Copy(source, a, source.Length);
            start = Environment.TickCount;
            Quicksort.SortInline(a);
            end = Environment.TickCount;
            total += end - start;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t\tTtl: {1}ms\tAvg: {2}ms", "Inlined", total, total / localRuns);

        total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < localRuns; i++)
        {
            Array.Copy(source, a, source.Length);
            start = Environment.TickCount;
            Quicksort.SortNonInline(a);
            end = Environment.TickCount;
            total += end - start;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("{0}\tTtl: {1}ms\tAvg: {2}ms\n", "Not inlined", total, total / localRuns);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a compilable example?

Comment: Could you post the full code you use, including the code you use to measure the time?

Comment: The just-in-time optimizer already inlines methods.  It can make better decisions than you, it actually knows what the machine code looks like and can judge whether inlining is truly an optimization or just leads to code bloat.  A real optimization is making the code smarter.  Optimizing QS is well documented, just look at the Wikipedia article for starters.

Comment: The measurements were taken using a `Stopwatch` instance. The `Stopwatch` instance was started immediately before the call to `QS()` and stopped on the line following the `QS()` call. I changed it to use `Environment.TickCount` but they gave the same results anyway.

Comment: The .NET quicksort has an inlined (and fairly smart) partition method. It also uses IComparable methods to do all comparisons, which one might expect to add overhead, but perhaps this is mitigated by the algorithm used in the partitioning step.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: I've added the main body of the program.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Based on the information given in the question, one can only guess and name some ideas.

Did you measure correctly? Keep in mind, in order to get reliable performance results, one should (at least)

- Run release builds without debugger attached
- Repeat the test sufficiently often and average the results
- Make the test fair, ie. give all test subjects the same 'ressource configuration'

In order to make sure, the source of the (assumed) performance drop is really connected to function inlining one can investigate the generated IL code. Or even better: the machine instructions generated by the JIT compiler.

For [ILNumerics](http://ilnumerics.net) we implemented a custom quick sort and did a lot of performance measures. The final algorithm is several times faster then the CLR version. Manual inlining is only one improvement, which was neccessary for better performance. Others are:

- Not using recursion
- Using unsafe comparison / swapping
- Using insertion sort for smaller partitions
- Optimzing for limited size of the temporary (stack replacement) array

Very often, the source for strange performance results is found in the way, memory is (mis)used by an algorithm. Another might lay in the different instruction flow which eventually more or less succeed in getting optimized by any compiler/processor involved. The overall execution performance is a highly complex beast, hard to guess deterministically and hence **a profiler is your best friend!**

**@Edit:** By looking at your main test routine, it appears, you are mainly measuring the memory bandwidth of your processor/main memory. A int[] array of length 5*10e6 is roughly 19 MB in size. This most probably is out of range of your caches. So the processor will wait for memory due to compulsory cache misses most the time. This makes a measure of the influence of any code reformulation hard to guess. I suggest to try to measure this way instead: (pseudo code)

- generate test data
- allocate array for copies
- iterate over number of global repetitions (let say 10)

  - inner repetitions for Array.Sort (eg. 1000)

    - copy the (unsorted) test data
    - sort the **copy** by Array.Sort
    - add time
  - average time for Array.Sort
  - inner repetitions for Quicksort.Sort (eg. 1000)

    - copy the (unsorted) test data
    - sort the **copy** by Quicksort.Sort
    - add time
  - average time for Quicksort.Sort
  - inner repetitions for Quicksort.Sort2 (eg. 1000)

    - copy the (unsorted) test data
    - sort the **copy** by Quicksort.Sort2
    - add time
  - average time for Quicksort.Sort2

The goal is to make the quicksort only use data from the caches. Therefore, make sure not to recreate the copies from new memory but rather have only two global instances: the original and the copy to get sorted. Both must fit into your (last level) cache at the same time! With some headroom (for other processes on the system) a good guess is to use up only half of the available last level cache size for both arrays. Depending on your true cache size, a test length of 250k seems more reasonable.

**@Edit2:** I ran your code, got the same results and watched the (optimized) machine instructions in the VS debugger. Here comes the relevant part from both versions:

```
Not inlined: 
    69:                 do { pIndex--; } while (arr[pIndex] > pivot);
00000017  dec         ebx 
00000018  cmp         ebx,esi 
0000001a  jae         00000053 
0000001c  cmp         dword ptr [ecx+ebx*4+8],edi 
00000020  jg          00000017 
    70:                 do { leftPoint++; } while (arr[leftPoint] < pivot);
00000022  inc         edx 
00000023  cmp         edx,esi 
00000025  jae         00000053 
00000027  cmp         dword ptr [ecx+edx*4+8],edi 
0000002b  jl          00000022 


Inlined: 
    97:                 do { pIndex--; } while (arr[pIndex] > pivot);
00000038  dec         dword ptr [ebp-14h] 
0000003b  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-14h] 
0000003e  cmp         eax,edi 
00000040  jae         00000097 
00000042  cmp         dword ptr [esi+eax*4+8],ebx 
00000046  jg          00000038 
    98:                 do { leftPoint++; } while (arr[leftPoint] < pivot);
00000048  inc         ecx 
00000049  cmp         ecx,edi 
0000004b  jae         00000097 
0000004d  cmp         dword ptr [esi+ecx*4+8],ebx 
00000051  jl          00000048
```

As can be seen, the 'Not inlined' version does better utilize the registers for decrementing the running index (Line 69 / 97). Obviously the JIT decided not to push and pop the corresponding register on the stack, because of other code in the same function is making use of the same register. Since this is a hot loop (and the CLR does not recognize this) the overall execution speed suffers. So, in this specific case, manually inlining the Partition function is not profitable.

However, as you know, there is no guarantee that other versions of the CLR do the same. Differences may even arise for 64 bit.

Comment: Thanks, I will continue to play around with the algorithm. I did attempt to get reliable results though by doing all three of your suggestions. I've attached the main program code if you're interested to compile it.

Comment: I've implemented your psuedocode and ran it with 200k items with the same results. :)

Comment: @joshhah I would like to run this test. can you post your code please?

Comment: well, its been only a guess ;-) If you post your (complete) code, I will look at the IL level.

Comment: @AnastasiaRushda Hi, I've put up the test code on [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/3Svd74mW)

Comment: @HaymoKutschbach I've also put up the quicksort code on [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/V18fw8cp)

The IL appears identical to me though...

Comment: Thanks! That's it! I had to turn off JIT optimization suppression in the debugging options to see this. Interestingly, optimization is applied to both the inline and non-inlined methods when building for x64.